# Ejecutar procedimiento que requiere parámetros con un JOB en oracle

Tags: oracle

Puedo lanzar un JOB que ejecute un procedimiento que requiere parámetros?

Cuando lanzo el JOB con parámetros me genera error justo en el parámetro que relaciono.

Ejemplo :

```
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(RT_job,'pkg_Escritura.prc_escribe(1,'||p_fecha_proceso||');',sysdate+0.00034722);
```

El error es la fecha de proceso. Pensé que era algo en el formato fecha, así que modifiqué todo para recibir `varchar` y mandé "xxxx" el error es "xxxx"

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, parece que no permite pasar fechas, probé cambiando el procedimiento para que recibiera un numero y así si funciono...

```
    v_sqldyn:='pkg_Escritura.prc_escribe.prc_escribe('||p_numero||');';
            insert into rt_prueba values(sysdate,v_sqldyn)
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(RT_job,v_sqldyn,sysdate+0.00034722);
```

Y asi funciona, pero cuando el parametro es fecha no lo acepta, pasa el mes en otro formato y no se deja ejecutar....alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no es 100% clara. Pero asumiendo que el tipo de `p_fecha_proceso` es `date`, y el parámetro para `prc_escribe` también es de tipo `date`, entonces, en efecto, puedo ver como Oracle se confunde al concatenar una fecha como un string, y puede que convierta la fecha incorrectamente.

No sé si es la mejor manera, pero lo siguiente debería funcionar usando fechas. La idea es que controles explícitamente como Oracle convierte (e interpreta) la conversión de fecha a string y de nuevo a fecha:

```
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(
  RT_job,
  'pkg_Escritura.prc_escribe(1, to_date(''' || to_char(p_fecha_proceso, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS''));',
  sysdate+0.00034722);
```

Notarás que el formato que uso (`YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`) incluye día y hora. Si no te importa la hora, por ejemplo, puedes usar simplemente: `YYYY-MM-DD`. Puedes ajustar el formato según lo que necesitas.